# How to traverse a json file and find the key name using value?

Tags: python, json

can anyone please help me to find the solution
I am having a JSON file like below

```
    {
   "Parent1": ["Child1", "Child2","Child5"],
   "Parent2": ["Child3", "Child4","Child5"]
    }
```

expectation: Python code to find the parent name using child name

> User input: Child1
> Expected output : Parent1

OR

> User input: Child5
> Expected output : Parent1,Parent2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an apporach you can use

```
choice = input("Enter search string ")
ans = []
for i,j in data.items():
    if choice in j:
        ans.append(i)
```

ans will now contain the keys you need as a list

Answer (score 0):

You should read the json file and then loop over the dictionary to find matching for the given input

```
def find_key_name_by_value(json_input, key_to_find):
    result = []
    for key, value in input.items():
        if key_to_find in value:
            result.append(key)
    return result

json_input = {
   "Parent1": ["Child1", "Child2","Child5"],
   "Parent2": ["Child3", "Child4","Child5"]
    }
result = find_key_name_by_value(json_input, "Child4")
print(result)
```

Comment: input is a reserved keyword in python, you should rename it to something different